# Topshelf: change windows service configuration

Tags: c#, .net, topshelf

I have a c# windows service developed using the Topshelf framework. The service reads configurable values from App.config. However, when I change values inside App.config and reinstall the windows service, it does not read the latest values.

Is there any intermediate step or execution of a Topshelf command required as part of this process?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you verified when you reinstalled that the correct values were in the app.config file copied to your install directory.

Comment: Yes, i directly updated the app.config file in my install directory

Comment: How are you reading values from the app.config? With ConfigurationManager?

Comment: That is correct, I am using the ConfigurationManager